# Wrong return data 1 instead 0 in ajax post data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have tried so many ways, research for half of day but could not figure out what could possibility wrong in my code, I have Ajax below:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://<?php echo $DOMAIN_NAME?>/extensions/set_featured.php",
    type: "post",
    data: {
        job_id: $("a.confirm").attr('data-jobId'),                                    
        title: $("a.confirm").attr('data-title'),
        job_featured: $("a.confirm").data('featured')
    },
    success: function (response) {
       // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 

    }
```

my HTML data is below:

```
<a href="#" class="confirm" data-title="Ưu tiên việc làm này?" data-jobId="<?php echo $value['id']?>" data-featured="<?php echo $value['featured']?>">
```

==> data-featured in HTML displays 0 normally like it should:

[image: data-featured]

But when I submit button Ajax data `job_featured` returns 1 instead 0 :

[image: data_featured returns 1 instead 0]

tried change `.attr()` to `.data()` didn't help.
When I set `data-featured` manually to 0 instead of PHP code, it is displays to 0 without problems.

I have no ideas what could possibility cause an issue in my code.
Any advise would be very appreciated :(

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: PHP is irrelevant here. Show us the HTML that the browser actually gets, not the PHP code that produces it.

Comment: Yes - and not a screenshot, but the actual HTML (do a "View Source", do not use the console)

Comment: Actually I have 3 fields id 75 -> 78, I guess there was my mistake that matching data without $(this). 

Thanks for advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you noticed that the `job_id` is `75` and not `78`?

`$('a.confirm')` gets all matching links with that class, not just the one you clicked. You may need to use `var link = $(this);` at the start of your event handler to correctly handle the link.

Comment: Yes, actually I have 3 fields id 75 -> 78, I guess there was my mistake that matching data without $(this). Thank you for correcting me :)